# Making two global.asax files in two different projects get called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a situation where I am in need of two project one MVC and one Web API.The reason this is done is because the web api project will be used externally by a mobile hybrid app.

Both projects have there own Global.asax files , but because the MVC project is set as the startup project only the global.asax of the mvc project gets called or at least that is what I observed.

I need a way to make the Global.asax of the web api project to also run because I want the project to be independent of the mvc project.At the moment the code for WebApiConfig is set in the mvc global.asax Application_Start() but I need it to set it in the global.asax if the WEB API project.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about in a Development Context within the IDE. i.e. when you start your project (Press `F5`) you want both projects to launch simultaneously ?

If so, you can set multiple start projects by

- Right click the solution file
- Set Start Up Projects
- Chose "Multiple Projects"
- Change the action on multiple projects to "start"

[image]